# Calling the Oracle function from Oledb Connection

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ado.net, oledbcommand

Hi i am trying to call the Oracle function using the following code but it is showing the error like

> "ORA-01403: no data found\nORA-06512: at \"TEST.VOD_BULK_TRANS1\",
>   line 47\nORA-06512: at line 1"

The function takes 3 input parameters and return one integer value.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn= new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    //set the command text (stored procedure name or SQL statement)
    command.CommandText = "VOD_BULK_TRANS1";

    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("retVal", OleDbType.VarChar, 11, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, true, 0, 0, "retVal", DataRowVersion.Current,null));
    command.Parameters.Add( OleDbParameter("@t_list", videosListWithCommaSeparated);
    command.Parameters.Add( OleDbParameter("@option1", 3);
    command.Parameters.Add( OleDbParameter("@id1", groupId);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Please suggest me the way how to call the function or stored procedure using the Oledb Conneciton.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a `Stored Procedure` with ado.net, you must set the [`CommandType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) property from your `IDbCommand` object to [`CommandType.StoredProcedure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx). For sample:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn= new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    // set the commend type here    
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    //set the command text (stored procedure name or SQL statement)
    command.CommandText = "VOD_BULK_TRANS1";

    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("retVal", OleDbType.VarChar, 11, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, true, 0, 0, "retVal", DataRowVersion.Current,null));
    command.Parameters.Add( OleDbParameter("@t_list", videosListWithCommaSeparated);
    command.Parameters.Add( OleDbParameter("@option1", 3);
    command.Parameters.Add( OleDbParameter("@id1", groupId);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```